# Argument of type 'typeof' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a module that other controllers in my application can use to determine what the right export formats are. I'm pretty new to TypeScript, and this error has me scratching my head:

I have two files - one that's the module, and the other is a file that stores a bunch of constants. The first file is `download_types.ts`

```
# imports the `RenderFormats` constant from my `download_types_constants` file
import RenderFormats from "./download_types_constants";
import _ from "underscore";
import angular from "angular";

export class DownloadType {
  downloadFormats(options: any) {
    if (options.canRenderElement) { return options.exportFormats; }

    const { exportFormats } = options;

    return _.omit(exportFormats, RenderFormats);
  }
}

export const ngModule = angular.module('myapp.common.scheduler', [])
  .service('DownloadType', DownloadType);
```

This is `download_types_constants.ts`:

```
export const RenderFormats = ["png"];
```

However, when I reload the page, I get the following error:

```
./delivery_formats/download_type.ts
(11,34): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof "/scheduled_plan_dialog/scheduled_pl...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type 'typeof "/scheduled_plan_dialog/scheduled_pl...'.
```

I am not quite sure what the problem is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing the default export from `./download_types_constants` rather than the array `RenderFormats`. The reported type error is a bit confusing as it refers to the last overload of `omit` (in which the second argument is a function.) It should work if you change the import to

```
import { RenderFormats } from "./download_types_constants";
```